# How do i build my project with sublime text 3 and scripts are not getting loaded for my debugging?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2012, google-chrome-devtools, sublimetext3

**Question 1 :**
I am using sublime text 3 to develop my site. How do i build my project and run(http://localhost:) as we do in visual studio?

**Question 2**
If i open the chrome browser from sublime text application for debugging it is just open from my local drive, so javascript files are not get loaded and i am getting blank white screen if i click the script file in the sources tab of dev tools . But the same javascript file get loads fine in the developer tools when i open the site from Visual Studio like http://localhost:.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sublime text 3 is just an editor so it doesn't have advanced features right out of the box like Visual Studio. You need to set up your own local host in your current working directory. There are many ways to achieve this. You can set up a simple static Python server, if you have Python installed in your machine, with `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` in your terminal console (or command prompt in windows). You should see this message

```
 Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 ...
```

Navigate to browser with url `http://localhost:8000/` and you'll see your html along with any javascript/css assets. When you make any changes to your html or asset files, you should restart your server.

I recommend using building tools like gulp or grunt for building projects in general. There are many tutorials online about how to set up automatic server restart and browser syncing using these tools.